# what is the standard way to provide content in multiple languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I understand I18n and how it can be used to internationalize your application. I am posed with a different challenge though - giving users the ability to provide content in two languages and having the application serve appropriate content based on locale.

Is there a standard, "rails" way of doing this? Does ActiveRecord provide anything that could be of help here "out of the box"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'Rails' way for such a specific use case, but you can consider serving I18n from ActiveRecord, which will allow you to customize your translations based on user input.

https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record might be useful.